# Output PCL from Word document using Python

Tags: python, django, openoffice.org, printer-control-language

I'm building a web application which will include functionality that takes MS Word (and possibly input from a web-based rich text editor) documents, substitutes values into the formfield placeholders in those documents, and generates a PCL document as output.

I'm developing in python and django on windows, but this whole solution will need to be deployed to a web host (yet to be chosen), which in practice means that the solution will need to run on linux.

I'm open to linux-only solutions if that's the only way. I'm open to solutions that involve talking to a server written in another language. I am able to write C++ or java if necessary to get this done. The final output *does* have to be in PCL format.

My question is: **what is a good tool chain for generating PCL from word documents using python**?

I am considering using some kind of interface to openoffice to open the word documents, do the substitutions, and send the output to some kind of printer driver. *Does anyone have experience with this? What libraries would you recommend?*

Options for interfacing that I have identified include the following; any other suggestions would be greatly welcomed:

- Ulif.openoffice: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ulif.openoffice/0.4
- Py3o.renderserver: https://bitbucket.org/faide/py3o.renderserver
- OpenOffice-python: http://openoffice-python.origo.ethz.ch/

A second approach would be to use something like paradocx ( https://bitbucket.org/yougov/paradocx/wiki/Home ) to open the word files, do the substitutions using that in python, then somehow interface with something that can output PCL. *Again, any experience or comments on this approach would be appreciated.*

I will very much appreciate any comments on tools and toolchains, and ideas or recipes that you may have.

This question covers similar ground to, but is not the same as: [How to Create PCL file from MS word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90401/how-to-create-pcl-file-from-ms-word)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so my final solution involved creating a java webservice to perform my transcoding.

- [Docx4j](http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j) provides a class `org.docx4j.convert.out.pdf.viaXSLFO.Conversion` which hooks into [apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) to convert Docx to PDF; that can be easily hacked to convert to PCL (because FOP outputs PCL)
- [Spark](http://www.sparkjava.com/) is a lightweight java web framework which allowed me to wrap my transcoder in a web service
- Because I also manipulate the document, I need to have some metadata, so the perfect thing is a multipart form. I decode that using [Apache Fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/)

In almost all cases, I had to upgrade to the development versions of libraries to get this to work.

On the python side I use:

- [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) to communicate with the web service
- [`poster`](http://atlee.ca/software/poster/index.html) to prepare the multi-part request

Answer (score 2):

Ghostscript can read PS (Postscript) or PDF and create PCL. You can use python libraries or just subprocess....

Comment: Thanks - do you know of python libraries for interfacing with ghostscript, or options for converting word to pdf in python? If you do, I will be very grateful if you can link to them.