# Extract XSL-FO from docx4j (or convert straight to PCL)?

Tags: ms-office, docx, apache-fop, printer-control-language, docx4j

Is there a way to extract the XSL-FO from docx4j, or is there a guide (or existing code) to adapting the docx4j pdf output to emit PCL instead of PDF?

The task I am doing is to fill in the fields of a (docx) word document (and optionally remove them or not - i.e. maybe leave them filled in, or replace them with their value), then transform to PCL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [pdf viaXSLFO](http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j/browser/trunk/docx4j/src/main/java/org/docx4j/convert/out/pdf/viaXSLFO/Conversion.java), which creates XSLFO as an intermediate step (and optionally saves it).

You can modify that to give you PCL output.  You'll need to change the line:

```
Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, os);
```

to

```
Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PCL, os);
```

and add appropriate PCL stuff to the FOP config string, and if you are lucky that'll be it!

Comment: I've actually just tried that - there's only a little more to it. I don't know how well it's worked, I'm looking for a pcl viewer!

Comment: Actually, this worked perfectly. I've summarised the tools and approach I took here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974074/output-pcl-from-word-document-using-python